# How to get html tags starting with 'abcd' using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have the following html code:

```
    <div class="pictures">
       <figure>
           <img src="img/foo.jpg" height="400" width="400" id="abcd001"/>
           <figcaption>foo</figcaption> 
       </figure>
       <figure>
           <img src="img/bar.jpg" height="400" width="400" id="abcd002"/>
           <figcaption>bar</figcaption> 
       </figure>
       <figure>
           <img src="img/Joe.jpg" height="400" width="400" id="abcd003"/>
           <figcaption>Joe</figcaption> 
       </figure>
   </div>
   <div id="abcd004">
       Lorem Ipsum.
   <div>
```

And am trying to obtain all html tags and their children whose ids start with 'abcd'. The query function of the XDOMDocument class does not seem to work with regex.

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->load("/var/www/html/myWebsite.html")

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xdom = $xpath->query("//img[@id='abcd*']");

foreach($xdom as $entry)
{
    echo $entry;
}
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: start-with does not work because that function does not seem to work on the IDs of html tags**

Comment: You are loading your page as XML (which is good if it it works), usually you would use [`loadHTML()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) which can cope with the bad markup in some pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using the correct syntax for `start-with`, try the following:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xdom = $xpath->query("//img[starts-with(@id, 'abcd')]");


foreach($xdom as $entry) {
    echo $entry->getAttribute('src') . "\n";
}
```

See it working here: https://3v4l.org/04i5a

Comment: I actually want the entire hml tag, ie I want `<img src="img/Joe.jpg" height="400" width="400" id="abcd003"/>` and `<div id="abcd004">
       Lorem Ipsum.
   </div>`